# Can’t create release iOS build in Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

This is error I get when I try to build distribution build.

```
Check dependencies
Code Signing Error: Mimic has conflicting provisioning settings. Mimic
is automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing
identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code
signing identity value to “iPhone Developer” in the build settings
editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type
’Application’ in SDK ‘iOS 11.0’
```

It works when I build in Developer mode, but the problem are push notifications then, they only work in sandbox mode if I build the app in Developer mode.

How to build the app in Distribution mode?

Comment: I have had this issue at command line.  Have you tried setting your distribution provision manually in xcode after building as development.  That has worked for me.

Comment: Not really. Can you please tell me how to do it

Comment: In Xcode under "signing", deselect "Automatically manage signing".  Next right below in the (Debug) and (Release) section manually select your distribution provisioning profile and try to run on your device.  It should build now. Also [this link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-io-ios-distribution-profile-packaging-error-code-sign-error-no-code-signing-identities-found-no-valid-signing-identities/64423) might be helpful

Comment: Been having the same problem all day, and the above hasn't fixed it... Any ideas? Is it a problem with the latest version of Xcode or Cordova perhaps?